# Can't install my own iOS app through vShare or iTunes on my jailbroken iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I just recently started to code a simple app for my phone and since I don't have $99 to fork out for a Developers License, I followed some steps online to make my own code-sign. I managed to do everything and export my .app into iTunes, so I plugged in my iPhone and tried to install it. No luck. Got the .ipa and uploaded it to media fire and tried to install it via vShare. I get the error "Delta-V Calculator Installation Failed". I'm not really sure what to do at this point, I guess I could starting saving up money if theres nothing left for me to do.

P.S. My app was made in Xcode 5 with the iOS 7.1 SDK, but my phone is running 7.0.6

Comment: have u tried it on simulator ?

Comment: you can use testflight sdk to install ipa on any device .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download JailCoder. After installing you'll be able to install your app just by clicking the Xcode run button!

Comment: Xcode crashes after patching it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Most likely. Because it runs perfectly for me. Uninstall Xcode (as you've messed up with it already as you said) and install it again. There are many threads for uninstalling Xcode, all around Stack Overflow as it leaves tons of cache in the system.

Comment: To be more specific, it launches and lets me select a project. Only picking my Delta-V app crashes it, I have another test project that didn't crash it

Comment: Have you patched the project?

Comment: Then as I said, you've messed up your Xcode. Uninstall it and install it. Doing stuff manually is fine, but such stuff can happen. So you left a trace. Just do what I said, it doesn't take so long. I patched a new project and it still works fine for me...